# Altering a value in array changes value in other array in Processing

Tags: arrays, processing

I know this question has been asked before in regards to Java, but I am currently trying out Processing and none of the solutions have worked for me. I have two arrays:

```
int[][] array1 = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
int[][] array2 = {{7,8,9},{10,11,12}};
arrayCopy(array1,array2);
array2[0][1] = 100;
println(array1[0][1]);
//prints 100 despite never altering it
```

Things I have tried:

```
//For Loop
for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
  array2[i] = array1[i];
}

//Cloning
array2 = array1.clone();
```

Comment: What is the implementation of the `arrayCopy` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you refer to the documentation for the [**`arrayCopy`**](https://processing.org/reference/arrayCopy_.html) function, it says

> If [**`arrayCopy`**](https://processing.org/reference/arrayCopy_.html) is used with a two (or three or more) dimensional array,
>   **it will only copy the references at the first level**, because a two dimensional array is simply an "array of arrays".

So essentially modifying any of the arrays within `array2` will also modify the corresponding array within `array1`. However, this would not be the case had you used a single dimensional array.

if you wish to copy each array of `array1` to `array2` without any of the said behaviour then you'll need to create a nested `for` loop which iterates through each of the elements (jagged array) of `array1` and copy their contents ( integers ) into another array.

example:

```
int[][] sequence = {{1, 2, 3}, 
                    {4, 5, 6}};
int[][] accumulator = new int[sequence.length][3];

for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) 
    for (int j = 0; j < sequence[i].length; j++) 
        accumulator[i][j] = sequence[i][j];
```

as a side note, avoid naming variables `array1`, `array2` etc. this makes it very difficult to identify the purpose of a particular variable. a variable should speak out what it does or its purpose by reading it.